# When did Apollo and Midnighter get married?

Tags: dc

Wikipedia only stated it was a the end of Millar's run of the comics, but when did it happen?

And also, where can I start reading about The Authority comics if I want to read about their entire relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I ended up just reading the entire first volume so I could see when it happens...)

Apollo and Midnighter got married in The Authority #29 (2002)
[image]
[image]

Which was the last issue of volume 1.